# sending formData using $http.post returns an empty body for larger files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to upload files through my web app. I have the following code:

View:

```
<div class="row">
  <form name="rsdCtrl.viewData.uploadForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-12">
    <div class="row voffset4">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="rsdCtrl.viewData.file" name="file" ngf-max-size="10MB" required/>
        <i ng-show="rsdCtrl.viewData.uploadForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large (max 10MB)</i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row voffset3">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button ng-disabled="!rsdCtrl.viewData.file || rsdCtrl.viewData.uploadForm.file.$error.maxSize" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="rsdCtrl.uploadFile()">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function uploadFile(){
  if (vd.uploadForm.file.$valid && vd.file) {
    $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
    return uploadService.upload(vd.file, "Convictions Calculator", "PCCS").then(function(response){
      vd.documentName = vd.file.name;
      vd.uploadedFilePath = response.data;
      $('#uploadModal').modal('hide').removeClass("in");
      $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
      alertService.setAlert('File uploaded', 'success');
    }).catch(handleServiceError);
  }
}
```

uploadService:

```
(function (){
'use strict';
angular.module('cica.common').service('uploadService', ['$http', '$window', '$routeParams', uploadService]);

function uploadService($http, $window, $routeParams) {

    this.upload = function (file, name, type) {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('document', file);
        let jobId = ($routeParams.jobId)? $routeParams.jobId: $routeParams.caseJobId;
        fd.append('jobId', jobId);
        fd.append('documentRename', name);
        fd.append('documentType', type);

        console.log(fd);
        return $http.post('/document/upload', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).catch(function(err){
            handleHttpError('Unable to upload document.', err);
        });
    };

    function handleHttpError(prefix, response){
        throw prefix + ' HTTP Status ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText;

    };
  }
})();
```

routes.js:

```
    'POST /document/upload': {controller: 'DocumentController', action: 'uploadDocument'},
```

DocumentController:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  uploadDocument: function (req, res) {
    const params = req.allParams();
    const jobId = params.jobId;
    const uploadedFileName = params.documentRename;
    const uploadedFileType = params.documentType;
    const awardsDirectoryKey = this.documentUploadDirectories.ADDITIONAL_AWARDS;
    req.file('document').upload({
        // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~100MB
        maxBytes: 100000000
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
        else if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
            return res.serverError('No file was uploaded');
        } else {
            const filePath = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
            const filename = DocumentService.addDateToDocumentName(uploadedFiles[0].filename);
            return fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.serverError(err);
                } else {
                    const jobId = params.jobId;
                    const jobVars =
                        {
                            filePath: results.filePath,
                            fileName: uploadedFileName,
                            fileType: uploadedFileType
                        };
                    return DocumentService.uploadConvictions(req.session.sessionId, jobId, jobVars).then(function (response) {
                        return res.send("Document uploaded.");
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        return res.serverError(err);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
```

If I upload a jpeg with a small picture (around 11kB) the upload works exactly as expected. However, If i try to upload a larger jpeg (around 170kB) it falls over. There is no immediate error thrown/caught though, what happens is the formData object created in the upload service seems to lose its data. If I insert this line into the DocumentController:

```
console.log(req.allParams());
```

the result prints the expected variables for the small file, but returns empty for the larger file, which eventually causes an error when the function tries to use these variables further on. Is there some kind of limit set to the size of file you can upload via this method, or have I configured this incorrectly?

Comment: You can use multer to upload file.https://github.com/expressjs/multer.  Add limit property value to the option object passed to multer.

Comment: @Anil Thanks for this, would prefer to avoid adding any more dependencies if possible, especially since my solution actually works for some examples. I feel the answer probably lies in how I've configured this solution, rather than the solution itself.